# Laravel 7 session break on IFRAME in a different domain

Tags: php, laravel, iframe

Am trying to develop an simple Laravel application here:

https://shopifyapp.sjranjan.com

This login is working fine. Now i pushed the above URL inside a iframe in this page...

http://thephpworld.com/iframe.php

When i try to login there it says... "419 Page Expired"

i see this error is related to CSRF token. I tried removing that also. Same issue remains.

**If i put inside a iframe in same domain it is working fine. But my requirement is that this app has to work on a iframe inside another website. How to deal with this ?**

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You need to pass token in ajax
var token = $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content");

Comment: actually it is not ajax call... it is same URL inside IFRAME... but in another domain.

Comment: bro ..is the problem solved? cause i faced the same problem currently..

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I finally fix this by editing config/sessions.php file by changing the following...

```
FROM 'same_site' => 'lax' TO 'same_site' => 'none'
```

Comment: I have a similar problem with a frontapp plugin (embedded iframe from Laravel app). Sentinel::guest() returns true on iframe even though I am logged in. sessions already set to same_site=>none