# laravel website session not working in iframe

Tags: php, laravel

Below is my laravel website in iframe. By means of token we validate and redirect user to dashboard page.

**`<iframe src="http://localhost/laravel-web-app/public/logincheck/f0c1bc3c965f5c59946f4bb49c2d7ccd01ab12e1035ea3c96d7dcc59b29e2d7d" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">`**

But on redirection session data of user is not working. I tried to change  config/session.php

```
'same_site' => 'none'
```

but actual laravel website is showing page expired. Can someone help to do session management inside iframe ?

I gone through this url also and it did not work : [Laravel 7 session break on IFRAME in a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62703394/laravel-7-session-break-on-iframe-in-a-different-domain)

Comment: Iframed _where_, on a different origin? Then these cookies would be considered “3rd-party”, and as such they are likely to be blocked by browser settings / privacy-enhancing extensions.

Comment: Did you tried to clear all laravel caches using artisan commands after changing same_site to none ?

Comment: @cbre : Yes its a different domain. by browser settings / privacy-enhancing extensions what should i do for this ?

Comment: @mbesson: i have ran php artisan cache:clear, after login its throwing 419
Page Expired

Comment: Samesite=None policy requires Secure=true in all modern browsers (though it's not a spec requirement) and therefore only works over https in practice

Comment: @apokryfos : Any suggestion on making iframe work with laravel website with session management

Comment: Make your laravel wesite work over https and your `iframe src='https://....` or make the site that is embedding your Laravel website the exact same domain as the Laravel website (in this case `http://localhost:80`) and then the cookie can be sent without any changes to the default policy

Comment: if iframe html and project are in same domain then it is working

Comment: @apokryfos if i make iframe src='https://.... in my localhost sessions are not working again

Comment: Open the developer console with F12 and check the network tab for the loading of the iframe and go to Cookies, it should give a reason as to why the session cookie was not sent

Comment: @apokryfos :     'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', true),   'same_site' => 'none', has made the things to work thanks.

Comment: @sivashanker The config file states same_site is used to mitigate CSRF attacks, what kind of effect will  'same_site' => 'none' have?

Answer (score 9):

Here is the resolution to make sessions working in iframe.
In config/session.php file of your laravel project

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE',true),
'same_site' => 'none',
```

this changes makes your session working in iframe and it also makes that same session to work on outside the iframe.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was for 2 days looking for a solution and the 'SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE' one was what was missing for me.

Comment: thanks for this! works like charm