# Laravel validation in an iframe cross-domain

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

It's a Laravel 8 simple form that gets validated by the laravel validator on submit and then repopulated using the `old()` helper.

The form works perfectly when accessed directly (or iframed on the same domain).

However, when iframed in the customer's website (which is on a different domain) the form **still works when submitted correctly**, but when submitted incorrectly the form just refreshes and doesn't return any validation errors or repopulate the form.

I've tried:

- Disabling the CSRF altogether;
- Just disabling it for this route - same behavior for both cases.
- Playing around with X-FRAME-OPTIONS in the Nginx configuration - no change.
- Using it in an iframe on another domain (not the customer's) - same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From this question
[laravel website session not working in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784103/laravel-website-session-not-working-in-iframe)
I found an answer that worked for me.

in config/session.php make sure the settings for secure and same_site are as follows

```
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE',true),
'same_site' => 'none',
```

So secure defaults to true, and same_site is set to 'none'.  The default I believe is 'lax'